# If this isn't the rate out then what exactly /is/ this equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm having some trouble with mixing problems and understanding some of the terminology. In this question, I thought I solved for the rate out of the solution from tank A (i didn't move on yet because then I got confused). I'm confused because we're already given the rate out is 5 gal/s? So what exactly did I solve for then?

Thank you in advance!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q_A(t)$ and $Q_B(t)$ be the amount of salt in tanks $A$ and $B$, respectively, at time $t$. Then

$$\frac{dQ_A}{dt} = \text{rate in $A$} - \text{rate out $A$} = 0 - 5\left(\frac{Q_A}{V_A}\right),$$

where $V_A(t)$ is the volume in $A$ at time $t$. Since the rate of volume entering $A$ equals the rate of volume leaving $A$, the net volume in $A$ does not change. So $V_A(t) = 100$, and thus $\frac{dQ_A}{dt} = -5\frac{Q_A}{100}$, i.e., $\frac{dQ_A}{dt} = -0.05Q_A$. Hence $Q_A(t) = Q_A(0)e^{-0.05t} = 20e^{-0.05t}$, which matches what you have so far.

To find $Q_B$, we need another differential equation:

$$\frac{dQ_B}{dt} = \text{rate in B} - \text{rate out B} = 5\left(\frac{Q_A}{100}\right) - 2.5\left(\frac{Q_B}{V_B}\right),$$

where $V_B(t)$ is the volumne in $B$ at time $t$. Since the rate of volume entering $B$ is $5$ gal/s and the rate volume leaving $B$ is $2.5$ gal/s, the net volume rate is $5 - 2.5 = 2.5$ gal/s. Therefore $V_B(t) = 200 + 2.5t$. Since $Q_A(t) = 20e^{-0.05t}$, we have

$$\frac{dQ_B}{dt} = e^{-0.05t} - \frac{2.5 Q_B}{200 + 2.5t}$$

or

$$\frac{dQ_B}{dt} + \frac{2.5 Q_B}{200 + 5t} = e^{-0.05t}.$$

Solve this equation by method of integrating factors, using the initial condition $Q_B(0) = 40$. Once you've found $Q_B(t)$, find the value $t^*$ for which $V_B(t^*) = 250$; your answer will be $Q_B(t^*)$.

Comment: OHHHHH.... I see ... so I solved for the //amount of salt//... Thank you so much for the mega detailed answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @NookLines no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Salt water is denser than pure water. Thus it is feasible to assume that the pure water does *not* mix with the salt water in tank $A$. At the moment tank $B$ contains 250 gal, the net gain of 50 gals means that 50 gal have flown out and 100 gal have flown in. Incidentally, this is the original content of $A$. Hence we may assume that precisely the original salt water has left $A$ (which therefore now contains only pure water - for the first time). By proportionality, 250 gal of salt water contain 50 lb of salt.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question & I'm so sorry haha--- but I still don't understand what exactly is I solved for at the end. I don't know what my function is supposed to represent :^S